# Javascript two dimensional string array update value

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, immutability

I have the following code:

```
var data = ["z wwwww ","www   w ","w b w ww","w w  p w","w    w w","wwbwp  w"," wy  www"," wwwww  "];
console.log(data[0][0]); // outputs "z"
data[0][0]="x";
console.log(data[0][0]); // still output "z". Shouldn't it show "x"?
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Strings are immutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two dimensional array is an array, that includes elements that are array's themselves. The example you provided is not a 2D array.

The element in question is in fact a `String`.

`data[0]` - Gives you the first element in your data array, which is a string.
`data[0][0]` - Gives you the first `character` of this string element.

In JavaScript, a `string` is a collection of characters, but it isn't an array itself. It can be transformed into a string with `string.split('')`.

Anyways, the reason it shows `z` instead of `x`, is because strings are immutable. That means their values can not change. Instead, new objects are created.

Comment: You can transform a string into an array with string.split('')

Comment: No, a string is not an array. It's a string.